# Why does iptables work on matching strings when using -m string "example.com"?

Tags: iptables

According to my information, it is better not to use the command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s example.com -j DROP
```

Because `example.com`  will be replaced in realtime with an ip address, which will not cover all possible ip addresses.

But if I use:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "example" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

Taken from this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/357890/how-to-block-sites-with-iptables) and I tested it myself, then I no longer need to worry about ip substitution, because "example" will match "example.com" and it will block it.

So if `iptables` only works with ip addresses, why does it work on names in the second case?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `-m string --string example`, it will match all IP packets where the payload contains the string `example`.

If you go to a page via HTTP and the page contains word `example`, the page is shown only partially, because your rule drops the packet that contains the word `example`.

The rule can also break many other protocols that use plain-text. It can also break encrypted connections if the encrypted payload would match to `example`.

You should use a filtering proxy to block your traffic, it is accurate and doesn't cause unwanted side-effects.

If you don't want to implement a filtering proxy, then a poor man's version is to block DNS queries for your target domain:

**EDIT** Removed `.com` due to the fact that DNS packets don't contain dots but length indicators.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m string --string example -j DROP
```

This will drop DNS queries for your target domain, effectively blocking the access to those domains. Clients will time out waiting for DNS reply, so the blocking is quite invasive.

Comment: DNS queries contain null bytes instead of dots - will this actually work?

Comment: They're not always null bytes, but length prefixes. For example, `\x07example\x03com\x00` would work. Note also that DNS is case-insensitive and clients can make queries in UPPER or even mIxEd case, so -m string has to be told to be case-insensitive as well. (Overall, a task better handled by actual DNS resolvers such as Unbound.)

Comment: @TeroKilkanen But if I do `-m string --string "google.com"` it breaks all google websites, even though all of them are https. So can we say that it tries to match `google.com` in the whole ip packet including the destination address and data?

Comment: The rule in question acts on response packets from destination server (INPUT chain), it does not act on the request packet sent by the machine itself. Therefore it doesn't match on SNI fields of TLS ClientHello messages.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot search for `example.com` in the URL as most websites now work via HTTPS exclusively.

Yes, in your example `iptables` will resolve `example.com` on a first invocation and in case its IP address changes this rule will no longer work but you could solve it by running e.g. a cron script which resolves example.com and if there's a new IP address it then gets added to your iptables rules via `-I` or `-A`.

Comment: But if you use `string --string "google"` this will block all google websites. So in the second case there is more than first invocation replacement going on..

Comment: The question's rule matches also DNS packets, therefore the DNS response from DNS server is dropped because of the rule.

Comment: SNI in HTTPS is also clear text. As such this answer is not correct. Most hosts these days do use SNI.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a pattern for strings. Yes, you got your aim. But! If you try to search anything ingluding "example" by google.com you cannt too. Be careful use this setting.

Comment: Thank you. So does it work by searching for "example" in the url?

Comment: From man iptables-extensions

   string
       This modules matches a given string by using some pattern matching strategy.
       It requires a linux kernel >= 2.6.14.

       --algo {bm|kmp}
              Select the pattern matching strategy. (bm = Boyer-Moore, kmp = Knuth-
              Pratt-Morris)

Comment: @light9876 It searches for "example" in the *entire packet*. The answer is slightly wrong because Google search is encrypted nowadays. But if I'm connected to IRC (unencrypted) and someone says the word "example" in IRC, my IRC connection will stop working. Or if I try to go to example.somewhere-else.com (the DNS response will be dropped). Or if I I load an *unencrypted* web page with the word "example" in it. Dropping traffic willy-nilly like this *will* cause strange problems.

Answer (score 0):

Because `example.com` have to be present in *header* of most request against server at *example.com*:

- If you sent an email, you will put `to: john@example.com` in the mail header.
- If you do some *HTTP* request against *example.com*, once DNS resolved, minimal request have to contain target host:

  ```
  host example.com
  example.com has address 123.45.78.89
  ```

  DNS request is done on a DNS server, not necessarly at example.com. (if not cached!)

  ```
  nc 123.45.67.89 80 <<eoRequest
  GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
  Host: example.com
  eoRequest
  ```

Of course, your `iptable` rule will only drop header packet, but following packet won't be understood by server, so will be dropped by server himself. Server logs and client window may prompt something like *`400 Bad Request`*